# Proper ideal and units proof

Tags: ring-theory, proof-writing, ideals

Show that an ideal $I$ of $R$ is proper if and only if it does not contain $1$ iff and only if it does not contain any units.
($1$ is the identity element)

I'll need to show 3 parts:

(1) $\implies$ (2): Let $I$ be a proper ideal and assume $1 \in I$. I want to show that $1 \notin I$.

(2) $\implies$ (3): Let $I$ be a proper ideal that doesn't contain $1$ and assume there are units in $R$. By the definition, units of $R$ are elements with multiplicative inverses. So I need to show that there aren't multiplicative inverses.

(3) $\implies$ (1): Assume there are no units in $R$ and then show that $I$ is a proper ideal. For this part I was thinking of doing something like this- Let $u \in I$ such that $u$ has a multiplicative inverse. Let $x \in R$. Then

\begin{align}u^{-1}x \in R;\\
x=u(u^{-1}x) \in I,\end{align}
so $R \subseteq I$ which implies that $I = R$. But this is a contradition so therefore $I$ must be a proper ideal.

I just need help completing the proof.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are working with rings that have an identity. Note that in that case there are always units in $R$, simply because the identity is a unit.

If $1\in I$ then $r=r1\in I$ for each $r\in R$ wich means that $I$ is not proper.

Conversely if $1\notin I$ then $I\neq R$ hence it is proper.

If $u\in I$ and $u$ is a unit then $r=r1=r(u^{-1}u)=(ru^{-1})u\in I$ for each $r\in R$ wich means that $I$ is not proper.

Conversely if $u\notin I$ for some unit $u$ then again $I\neq R$ hence it is proper.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Contrapositively, it is the special case $\,j = 1\,$ of the following

$$\,I\supseteq (j)\iff j\in I\iff k\in I\ \ {\rm for\ some}\ \ k\mid j$$

Answer (score 0):

(1) $\implies$ (2):

> Show that if $1 \in I$, then every element of $R$ is in $I$. (Use the fact that $I$ is closed under multiplication by elements of $R$.)

(2) $\implies$ (3):

> Show that if a unit $u$ is in $I$, then $1$ is also in $I$. (Again, use the fact that $I$ is closed under multiplication by elements of $R$.)

(3) $\implies$ (1):

> If $I$ does not contain units, then it does not contain $1$, so it must be proper.

Answer (score 0):

You actually proved $(1) \Longrightarrow (3)$, because you assume $I$ is a proper ideal and get a contradiction by assuming it has a unit. You can't just write "Assume there are no units and let $u$ be a unit", that's already a contradiction, but you prove nothing.

There's a lot of negations in your statements so I suggest you restate your problem to show equivalence between:

$(1')\ I = R$.

$(2')\ 1 \in I$.

$(3')$ there's a unit $u \in I$.

You can see that $(1') \Longrightarrow (2')$ and $(2') \Longrightarrow (3')$ are trivial.

The only remaining thing is to prove $(3') \Longrightarrow (2')$, but that's exactly what you did, for any $x \in R$ it must be $(x u^{-1})u \in I \Longrightarrow x \in I$.